# Density function as Radon Nikodym derivative. Proving absolute continuity of pushforward measure

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Assume we have a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal F,P)$, a measure space $(\mathbb R,\mathscr B,\lambda)$ and a $\mathcal F$-measurable function $X:\Omega\rightarrow \mathbb R$.

Then let $\mathcal G:=\sigma(X)$ be the smaller sigma algebra on which $X$ is measurable, clearly $\mathcal G\subseteq\mathcal F$.

Then define the image measure (distribution) of $X$ under $P$ as $$P(X^{-1}(B))$$for any $B\in\mathscr B$.

Then in order to apply the Radon-Nikodym theorem we need that
$$P(X^{-1})<<\lambda$$
so then one could claim that there exist a $\mathcal G$-measurable function
 $f\geq0$ such that $$P(X^{-1}(B))=\int_Bfd\lambda$$

I am trying to see in which cases it holds that
$$P(X^{-1})<<\lambda$$

Suppose $B=\{x\}$ for some $x\in\mathbb R$, and assume furthermore that $X=x$ is a constant random variable (or you can suppose that it takes a value of $x$ in a measurable interval of $\Omega$).
Then $\lambda(\{x\})=0$ but, $P(X^{-1}(x))=P(\Omega)=1$, and then we are not satisfying the condition.

So for instance if I have a random variable that has both, continuous and discrete parts, can I construct a density of its distribution?

Thanks in advance for any comment.

Comment: Are you trying to prove that $P(X^{-1}) << \lambda$?

Comment: @Tom In practice yes, I want to prove this (or to know in which cases it holds) since this is the basic condition to claim that the distribution of some random variable $X$ has a density.

Comment: But that s not true in general! You just gave the simplest of the counterexamples!

Comment: But then if I have a random variable that has discrete and continuous parts, how could I construct (if it's possible) a density of its distribution?

Comment: You mean a density for the *continous part* of the distribution?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%27s_decomposition_theorem

Comment: In general every probability measure on $\mathbb{R}$ can be decomposed into the sum of a singular measure and an absolutely continuous (wrt Lebesgue) measure. If you wanna have the density of the continous part you need to differentiate its cdf.

Comment: Yes Tom that's precisely what I wanted to say, I didn't know about the Lebesgue decomposition, I'll give it a look. Thank you both!

Comment: @Tom You mean that every probability measure on $\mathbb R$ can be decomposed into the sum of a singular measure, an absolutely continuous measure, and a discrete measure, right?

Comment: @Math1000: Discrete measures are also singular. I think what you are referring to is a sum of a discrete, a singular *continuous*, and an absolutely continuous part.

Comment: Be careful.. one dicothomy is absolutely continuous vs singular another is "diffuse" (atomless) vs purely atomic. The decomposition in a. continuous + singular is the RN thm which is very deep. The decomposition in diffuse + purely atomic is almost trivial

Comment: @PhoemueX Yes, that is what I meant.